# Does youtube allow to embed live chat comments on mobile as of 2020?

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

In some previous threads the api was working (latest december 2019). In may 2020 it's not working again and there is nothing about live_chat not working on mobile in the documentation here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en . On web you can embed and the comments are shown correctly on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have found there is currently no way to embed YouTube chat on Mobile. The ways that I have found in the past look to be patched and no longer are supported or work.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en

Comment: That looks like a general chat UI help doc rather than one for embedding - did you paste the right URL?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26741381)

Comment: @service-paradis It is an answer, the answer is: _"From what I have found there is currently no way to embed YouTube chat on Mobile."_